# Swift - NavigationBar with TabBar not working well

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar, navigationcontroller

In my case, I'm making an app for real-time chat. I'm using large titles and search bar inside of my main view. However I wanted to add tabBar to my app navigationController and tabBar not working correct.

NOTE: I'm doing everything with code, please not tell me about storyboard.

Here is what supposed to be:

[image]

What is happening when I add tabBar:

[image]

AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabBarController())

    return true
}
```

TabBarController.swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let messagesController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MessagesController())
    messagesController.tabBarItem.title = "Sohbetler"
    messagesController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "chats")

    viewControllers = [messagesController]
}
```

Comment: Y do you need navigation controller for TabBarController ? You can remove that UINavigationController that would resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks but chirag's suggestion made everything correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put two navigation one for tabbar and second for controller hide one navigation bar and your problem will solve

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let objNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabBarController())
    objNav.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    window?.rootViewController = objNav

    return true
}
```

Comment: Waiting for time limit, I will :)

Answer (score 0):

try the following line in your viewcontroller where you want to show the tabbar

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```